# Spring Batch : Read from database and post to third party webserivce

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I need to develop an application to perform the following activities using Spring Batch.  Read data from the database --> Process data and prepare rest API request --> Write or Post into third party restful service.

I have seen a lot of examples for reading from the database to write to CSV, DB, JMS. 
But I don't find any options to write into web service. Is it possible to perform this activity using spring batch or please suggest some other technology.

Comment: Maybe really Spring Integration: http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch does not have a `RestItemReader` since the possibilities are a bit too great as to what we'd need to send.  That being said, writing your own `ItemWriter` implementation that uses a `RestTemplate` to send the data would be very straight forward to do.